# Access an internal network Webcam from outside (www)?

Tags: javascript, apache, url, networking, webcam

we have a webcam installed in our internal network.

I wrote a JavaScript in a HTML-File, which gives access to the stream through a BaseURL. I put it on our webserver, which is online (www). When I access the access the page through our internal network, it works of course and I can see the livestream.

If I access the website from my mobile phone (not in the network), the website loaded, but I don't see the livestream, because it is a webpage-url in our internal network.

I tried rewrite on the apache, but i think this is not the right way.

Has anyone an idea how to access the livestream of the camera?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some server side language like ASP.NET, Node.js, ruby, php, python, etc., and connect to your webcam to pull out the stream and then send it to the browser. The server side platform will be acting as a kind of proxy.